# table width doesn't work on multiple row

Tags: html, css, email

http://jsfiddle.net/qse5owx6/

Just sick, tried to debug this for an hour. Why the table is stretch by the content? I have wrap the layout properly with `tr` and `td`. I'm designing html for emails.

why the **width:600px** doesn't work on the table?

Comment: i don't understand . what exactly is the problem ? please be more specific

Comment: @MihaiT why the **width:600px** doesn't work on the table?

Answer (score 0):

see here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/qse5owx6/6/)**

well this happens because you've set specific fixed widths ( in pixels ) to all the elements , that's why you can't   force the table to a smaller width.

i suggest you use percentages as widths for the elements inside the table. for example

```
tbody { width:100%;}
tr { width:100%;}
td { width:50%;}
```

OR if you want to keep the widths of the elements fixed (873px) you could wrap all the table inside a div like `.wrapper` and add

```
.wrapper {
  width:600px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

see here : **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/qse5owx6/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

I did some research to create email templates.

I hope this will help you in this.

The steps to create email templates are:

1. Create the email template as per the guidelines of [article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919)
2. Once the template is ready, transfer all CSS from css files to `<style>` in `<head>`
3. Make all the CSS inline using [service](https://inliner.cm/)
4. To check which tag and CSS elements are valid for email client, please check [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)